# Can I work in Austria if I have an Italian residency card?

Tags: resident-permit, eu, italy, austria, documentation

If I want to work in Austria, do I have the same rights as EU citizens if I have an Italian long-term resident card?

Answer (score 2):

You do not have the same rights as EU citizens, but you do have a right to move to most other EU countries under certain conditions (excluding the UK, Ireland, and Denmark, so including Austria).  This is laid out in [directive 2003/109/EC](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02003L0109-20110520).  In Particular, it is covered in Chapter III, which contains articles 14 through 23.